# Immediate window - how to call a function from a DLL which has hyphens, periods and numbers in its filename?

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017, immediate-window

I want to run this in the immediate window:

```
?(char*)mono-2.0-bdwgc.dll!mono_pmip((void*)0x0000017866931945)
```

I get this back:

```
identifier "mono" is undefined
```

The DLL with that name is definitely loaded.

I have tried encasing the DLL name in quotes, parentheses, backticks etc - I get either "unrecognised token" or the same error.

From playing around with the DLL name (giving fake names!), it looks like the issue is the combination of the hyphens, numbers, and the period. Removing any of those from the DLL name gives a "Module X not found" error instead, suggesting it's at least recognising it.

Is there some way I should be typing this to make it be recognised? Or perhaps this is a Visual Studio bug?

I am using Visual Studio 2017 version 15.7.1. The DLL comes from a game built with Unity 2018.1.0f2, Windows 64 Standalone, .NET 4.6 runtime.

Context: This unity document (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/WindowsDebugging.html) instructs users to run the above command in the immediate window to retrieve managed symbols from a crash dump - but the document is outdated, and recent versions of Unity with a newer mono runtime actually use "mono-2.0-bdwgc.dll" instead of "mono.dll", so I'm trying and failing to adapt!

Comment: C++ dll plugin? If so, add your code. Both the C++ and the C# side that shows how you're calling it.

Comment: No, no native plugins - I'm trying to retrieve managed symbols from a crash dump callstack. And this is the Mono DLL itself I'm talking about, not my own. The issue is that the immediate mode doesn't recognise the Mono DLL name.

Comment: Ok. I see what you'r doing

Answer (score 2):

You can quote using the alternate/quoting context syntax:

```
? {,,mono-2.0-bdwgc.dll}mono_pmip((void*)0x0000017866931945)
```

Comment: If this works: thank you very much!! I will remember to try out this answer for next time I need to do this!

Answer (score 0):

Use the braced version of the [context operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/context-operator-cpp).

[From the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/context-operator-cpp):

> There are two ways of specifying context:
>
> 1. *{,,[module] } expression*
>
>    The braces must contain two commas and the module (executable or DLL) name or full path.
>
>    For example, to set a breakpoint at the `SomeFunction` function of EXAMPLE.dll:
>
>    ```
>    {,,EXAMPLE.dll}SomeFunction
>    ```
>
> ...
>
> - *module* is the name of a module. You can use a full path to disambiguate between modules with the same name.
>
>   **If the module path includes a comma, an embedded space, or a brace, you must use quotation marks around the path so that the context parser can properly recognize the string**. Single quotation marks are considered part of a Windows file name, so you must use double quotation marks. For example,
>
>   ```
>   {,,"a long, long, library name.dll"} g_Var
>   ```
>
>   ...